# InDesign: Text spacing having no effect on anchored object

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-wrap

I have an anchored object (graphic) inside a textframe. The positioning is set to "inline". Text-Wrap to "jump object".

[image]

[image]

Now I am trying to get a consistent distance above my headings throughout my document by changing the "space before" value. My anchored object, however, does not seem to fazed by that in the slightest bit ... not to say it is ignoring the setting completely. See this video for evidence:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S804CVWt-N8

This surely is a rather simple and dumb mistake I am making, but anchored objects and text wrap in general are kind of giving me a hard time, so help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like your anchored object is on the same line than your header. (Would be great if your video included invisible characters).

Comment: Ah, sry. I’ll see to upload a new one later today when I’m home

Comment: No need for a new video really. I'm pretty sure my guess isn't too bad. Just insert your anchored object in a different paragraph (using the editor tool to locate and add a return after your anchored object might be handy) Watch out for which paragraph style will be applied to the paragraph that holds your object though. Text wrap and changing Y offset should not even be necessary.

Comment: Either I haven't quite understood what you were getting at or it did not solve my problem:
https://imgur.com/a/mqUxP
This is what I got now, it is in its own paragraph, applied style is my standard body 1 paragraph style that is also used be the paragraph above :(

Comment: I also redcued the opacity to better visualise my problem with the object overlapping my text. I also tried all of the different text-wrapping styles but they barely change anything

Comment: Any chance you have a vertical shifting applied to your anchored object?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know what that means exactly? Could you elaborate further on where to find said option? Also I now switched the objects from "inline" to "above line" which seems to work. At least text wrap works now without me offseting the object to account for its heigth